# need to search for values in each string of an array to construct another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [count] => 12
    [6] => CN=G_Information_Services,CN=Users,DC=hccc,DC=campus
    [7] => CN=WEBadmin,CN=Users,DC=hccc,DC=campus
    [9] => CN=G_ISDept,CN=Users,DC=hccc,DC=campus
    [10] => CN=STAFF,CN=Users,DC=hccc,DC=campus
)
```

and I want to create an array of values that consist of the value between the first CN= and , of each array value below.

I probably will have to loop thru the array above, do a regex search for the first occurrence of cn and the value that follows it

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I need the final result to be an array that resembles this:

> array('G_Information_Services', 'WEBadmin', 'G_ISDept', 'STAFF');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) on each of the array values to get  *only the first* corresponding CN value.

```
$found = array();

foreach ($arr AS $values) {
    if (preg_match('/CN=([^,]+),/',$values,$matches))
        $found[] = $matches[1];
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => G_Information_Services
    [1] => WEBadmin
    [2] => G_ISDept
    [3] => STAFF
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (not the most efficient way but it should work):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if (is_numeric($key))
    {
        $array[$key] = explode(',', $array[$key]);
        $array[$key] = $array[$key][0];
        $array[$key] = substr($array[$key], 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: just realized I need to use a string search function to pull the appropriate value from the first occurrence of cn=

Answer (score 1):

This gets the first value of CN= of each element of the array, it also ignores any DC= values.

```
$arr = array(
    'count' => 12,
    6 => 'CN=G_Information_Services,CN=Users,DC=hccc,DC=campus',
    7 => 'CN=WEBadmin,CN=Users,DC=hccc,DC=campus',
    9 => 'CN=G_ISDept,CN=Users,DC=hccc,DC=campus',
    10 => 'CN=STAFF,CN=Users,DC=hccc,DC=campus'
);

$newArr = array();

foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    if($key != 'count')
    {
        $temp = explode(',', $value);

        foreach($temp as $item)
        {
            if(strpos($item, 'CN=') === 0)
            {
                $item = substr($item, 3 );
                $newArr[] = $item;
                break 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($newArr);
```